# Checking if a number is present in string

Tags: python

I have a working function that takes an input as string and returns a string. However, I want my function to return an empty string (`""`) if the input contains any number in whatever position in the string.

For example :

```
>>> function("hello")
```

works fine

```
>>> function("hello1")
```

should return `""`

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: What have you tried to tackle this issue? What is your current code?

Answer (score 0):

The main thing you need for that is the method "isdigit()" that returns True if the character is a digit.

For example:

```
yourstring="hel4lo3"
for char in yourstring:
  if char.isdigit():
    print(char)
```

Will output 4 and 3.

I think it is a good exercise for you trying to do your code from that!